# podspecによるzipファイルのDL、.hファイル、.aファイルのリンク方法

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

iOS開発のcocoapods, podspec周りで困りごとがあり、どなたかお分かりになる方ご教示いただけると大変助かります

現在ローカルのpodspecファイルにて、ライブラリ ([ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a.zip](https://www.epson.jp/dl_soft/file/31124/ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a.zip)) を直接DLし、その中の以下のファイルをxcodeプロジェクトへ追加しようとしています。

・ePOS2.h
・ePOSEasySelect.h
・libepos2.a
・libeposeasyselect.a

しかし、podspecファイルの書き方が間違っているのか `pod install` をしてもエラーが出てしまいます。
（ビルドクリーンを行った上で試しても同様でした）

**エラー:**

```
‘ePOS2.h’ file not found
```

また、zipファイルをDLしてePOS2.hを直接プロジェクトへ追加すると上記エラーは消えますが、今度はepos2.aが見つからないという旨のエラーが出るので、podspecファイル内の上記.hと.aのファイルの指定の辺りで何か誤りがあって正しくプロジェクトへリンクができていないのだと予想しています。

`pod spec lint` が通ることや、zipファイルのパスを変えるとそこでエラーが出ることも確認しているので、zipファイルパスの指定までは正しくできているのかなと考えております。

以下がpodspecファイルの内容です。

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = 'ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a'
  s.version      = '2.14.0'
  s.summary      = 'Epson ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0 for iOS'
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                    The Epson ePOS SDK for iOS is an SDK aimed at development engineers who 
                    are developing iOS applications for printing on an EPSON TM printer and 
                    an EPSON TM Intelligent printer.
                    Applications are developed using the APIs provided by Epson ePOS SDK.
                    Epson ePOS SDK for Android for Android devices is also provided in 
                    Epson ePOS SDK.
                    For detailed information, please see Epson ePOS SDK for iOS User's Manual.
                   DESC
  s.homepage     = 'https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=58'
  s.license      = { :type => 'Commercial', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author       = { 'SEIKO EPSON CORPORATION' => 'contact@epson.com' }
  s.platform     = :ios, '11.0'

  # zipファイルのURLと、`:flatten => true`を指定する.
  s.source  = { :http => "https://www.epson.jp/dl_soft/file/31124/ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a.zip", :flatten => true }

  s.source_files  = '*.h'
  #===以下ダメだった方法
  # s.source_files  = 'ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a/**/*.h'
  # s.source_files  = 'ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a/*.h'
  # s.source_files  = 'ePOS2.h'
  # s.source_files  = '**/*.h'
  # s.source_files  = 'ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a/ePOS2.h'

  s.preserve_paths  = '*.a'
  #===以下ダメだった方法
  # s.preserve_paths  = 'ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a/**/*.a'
  # s.preserve_paths = 'libepos2.a'
  # s.preserve_paths  = '*.a'
  # s.preserve_paths  = '**/*.a'

  s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'CoreGraphics', 'ExternalAccessory'
  s.library   = 'epos2', 'eposeasyselect', 'z', 'xml2.2'
  # s.library   = 'z', 'xml2.2'
  # s.xcconfig  =  { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a"' }
  s.xcconfig  = { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/ePOS_SDK_iOS_v2.14.0a/**"' }
end
```

どこか間違いがありますでしょうか？
どなたかお分かりになる方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけますと大変助かります。

Comment: 参考にさせていただいたサイトはこちらになります。
https://qiita.com/huin/items/54b5a1778cec0bf44ad0

Comment: 「今度はepos2.aが見つからないという旨のエラーが出る」のは、podspecファイルの下から5行目の`s.library   = 'epos2', 'eposeasyselect', 'z', 'xml2.2'`で、'epos2', 'eposeasyselect'の頭に`lib`が付いていないのが関係しているかも？

Comment: 仕様的に先頭のlibは省略するようなのです＞＜（実際に消してみてもそのようなメッセージと共にエラーになりました）

Comment: そうするとEPSONのサポート窓口に直接聞いてみるのが早いでしょうね。あとはStar精密のこちらを参考にしてみるとか。[Docs » 2. StarPRNTアプリケーション構成方法](https://www.star-m.jp/products/s_print/sdk/starprnt_sdk/manual/ios_objc/ja/configure_application.html)

Comment: kunifさんご丁寧にありがとうございます！！いただいた情報も参考に引き続き考えてみます！大変助かります。